# Check if at least one column contains a string in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to check whether several columns contain a string, and generate a Boolean column with the result. This is easy to do for a single column, but generates an Attribute Error (`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'`) when this method is applied to multiple columns.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

c1=[x+'x' for x in 'abcabc']
c2=['Y'+x+'m' for x in 'CABABC']
cols=['A','B']

df=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(c1,c2)),columns=cols)
df
```

Returns:

```
    A   B
0   ax  YCm
1   bx  YAm
2   cx  YBm
3   ax  YAm
4   bx  YBm
5   cx  YCm
```

The following code works when applied to a single column, but does not work when applied to several columns. I'd like something that fits in here and gives the desired result:

```
df['C']=df[cols].str.contains('c',case=False)
```

Thus the desired output is:

```
    A   B   C
0   ax  YCm True
1   bx  YAm False
2   cx  YBm True
3   ax  YAm False
4   bx  YBm False
5   cx  YCm True
```

Edit: I updated my example to reflect the desire to actually search for whether the column "contains" a value, rather than "is equivalent to" that value.

Edit: in terms of timings, here's the benchmark I'd like to be able to match or beat, without creating the new columns (using a `*1000` to the columns in my toy example):

```
newcols=['temp_'+x for x in cols]

for col in cols:
    df['temp_'+col]=df[col].str.contains('c',case=False)

df['C']=df[newcols].any(axis=1)
df=df[['A','B','C']]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option via `applymap` :

```
df['C'] = df.applymap(lambda x: 'c' in str(x).lower()).any(1)
```

Via `stack/unstack`:

```
df['C'] = df.stack().str.contains('c', case=False).unstack().any(1)
df['C'] = df.stack().str.lower().str.contains('c').unstack().any(1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
    A    B      C
0  ax  YCm   True
1  bx  YAm  False
2  cx  YBm   True
3  ax  YAm  False
4  bx  YBm  False
5  cx  YCm   True
```

Comment: This is nice - it scales pretty well compared to the apply method. Some quick timings on a df 1000X this size: applymap takes about 12ms, while apply takes over 1.25 seconds. stack/unstack takes 41ms. The fastest is a multi-line piece of code I wrote (now in question) that runs the str.contains code for each column, then compares the columns using any(), but it is only marginally faster at 7.25 ms. I also wonder if applymap may scale better as more columns are added.

Comment: I realized that changing `df.applymap(.)` to `df[cols].applymap(.)` makes `applymap` the fastest method (beating the benchmark in my question, as desired).

Answer (score 1):

I would run an apply across the columns and take the `any()` of those:

```
df['C']=df.apply(lambda y: y.str.contains('c',case=False),1).any(1)
```

Comment: the `str` functions are only available by a `pd.Series`, not the dataframe, because a dataframe doesn't have a single type.

Comment: Running this code also generates an attribute error: `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!`

Comment: Only if you have already created the column 'C'. :)